# CLion does not resolve my std lib header symbols

Tags: cmake, mingw, clion

I started a project on linux and now want to build it on Windows 10. Therefore I use CLion as my IDE. CLion unfortunately could not resolve standard header symbols. Please see screenshots of my setup.

My Toolchain:
[image]

My CMake Setup:
[image]

My project tree:

[image]

Examples of the issue:
[image]

My CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(vilsoc)

include_directories(include)
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")

set(LIBS sfml-graphics sfml-window sfml-system)

if (WIN32)
    set(SFML_DIR "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Libraries\\sfml-2.5.1-vs15-32bit")
    find_package(SFML 2.5 COMPONENTS graphics audio REQUIRED)

    if(NOT TARGET spdlog)
        # Stand-alone build
        set(SPDLOG_DIR "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\spdlog-1.3.1")
        find_package(SPDLOG REQUIRED)
    endif()

endif (WIN32)

add_executable(vilsoc main.cpp ${SOURCES})
if (WIN32)
  target_link_libraries(vilsoc ${LIBS} spdlog::spdlog)
endif (WIN32)
if (UNIX)
  target_link_libraries(vilsoc ${LIBS})
endif (UNIX)
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/logs")
```

I want to point out that `spdlog::info` is a 3rd part DLL I use. If somebody can also give me a hint how to get this one resolved I would be thankful, too. But first I would love to have the standart headers being resolved.

Comment: Please provide your CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: @VictorSergienko added as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks.

On Mac/clang, CLion 2019.2 parses your project correctly; it rightfully doesn't find `spdlog` and `sf` namespaces, as they are not included.

The "standard headers on Windows" issue may be rooted in [mingw64](https://dev.my-gate.net/2014/09/15/how-to-use-mingw-w64-with-clion/), it's not actively supported. The mentioned hack may or may not help. If switching to Visual Studio compiler is an option, try it.

If you are desperate, set the explicit path to standard library with [`include_directories(SYSTEM <dir1>)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html).

Comment: How does one get it to find these namespaces on Mac?